# Scan DIVs for specific classes to generate unique links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of divs containing images/videos/galleries etc.
The structure is as follows:

```
<div class="item image">image content</div>
<div class="item video">video content</div>
<div class="item gallery">gallery content</div>
<div class="item image">image content</div>
<div class="item image">image content</div>
<div class="item video">video content</div>
```

As you can see, there can be more than one div with the same content type.
What I want to achieve is scan the list of divs with class=item and generate a button for each content type.

This is what I have so far, using jQuery EACH function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".item").each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("image")) {
            alert('image found');
        };
        if ($(this).hasClass("video")) {
            alert('video found');
        };
    });
});
```

Problem is the alert get executed multiple times, for each div with the class equal to my condition. As I am planning to generate buttons for each content type this current code will add duplicate buttons as more than one div can have a class of video/image.

I have tried using "return false" inside the IF condition but that breaks my whole EACH function, stopping it at the first reference.

Comment: where's your button generating code..?

Comment: add a variable per content type that you set to false?

Comment: I don't have that code yet, as this EACH function has priority, let me change the question title then.

Comment: How many types can there be?

Comment: There can be up to 10 content types: audio, video, quote, link, image, gallery, status, chat

Comment: Why not just use an array of booleans then print after that runs?

Comment: Alex & drew_w: I get the feeling the solution is simple, would you mind posting a sample of your answer?

Comment: `};` for ending `if()` ? wrong syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a temporary variable that keeps track of which item types you have already traversed

```
(function() {
    var types = {},
    type_re = /\b(?:audio|video|quote|link|image|gallery|status|chat)\b/g;

    $('.item').each(function() {
        var m = this.className.match(type_re);

        if (m !== null && !types.hasOwnProperty(m[0])) {
            // code to add button
            console.log('add button for type ' + m[0]);

            types[m[0]] = true;
        }
    });
}());
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/coliyuxo/1/)

#### Previous answers

You can create an array first that will contain all the types found in the document:

```
var types = [],
type_re = /audio|video|quote|link|image|gallery|status|chat/g;

$('.item').each(function() {
    var m;

    while ((m = type_re.exec(this.className)) !== null) {
        if (!$.inArray(types, t[0])) {
            types.push(t[0]);
        }
    }
});

// types is an array with all types found
```

Alternatively, iterate over all possible types and filter the items based on each type:

```
var $items = $('.item'),
types = ['audio', 'video', 'quote', 'link', 'image', 'gallery', 'status', 'chat'];

$.each(types, function(_, type) {
    var $itemsOfType = $items.filter(function() {
        return (' ' + this.className + ' ').indexOf(type) != -1;
    });
    if ($itemsOfType.length) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, your solution also works right out of the box (like Alex'es). Before I select the best answer, which one would you say is more efficient?

Comment: Hook it up to jsperf and check the performance; I can't really tell because I don't know the document size, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Some really easy approach would be to add a status variable for each possible content type and check it:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {        
    var _image = true,
        _video = true;
    $( ".item" ).each(function() {

      if ($(this).hasClass( "image" ) && _image) {
        _image = false;
        alert('image found');
      };
      if ($(this).hasClass( "video" ) && _video) {
        _video = false;
        alert('video found');
      };

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, your solution worked right out of the box, now I get an alert only once, for each post type (div) even if there are multiple displayed on page. Is this code efficient though?

Comment: yes, it is. if statements of that length dont really matter due to performance

Comment: it would be faster if you would put the _image as first condition to check, like so: `if (_image && $(this).has...)`

Comment: Wished I could have selected two best answers but I had to go with Jack's code as its a lot shorter and also works out of the box. Thanks a lot!

Comment: i am not hunting for reputition but i am pretty sure testing booleans is way more efficient than reading/writing arrays. but jacks approach looks more professional. as i said, my approach is very simple

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
if($(".image").length>0)
  {
      alert("image Found")
      //generate button
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an object in your jQuery ready function. When finished looping, write your buttons using the buttons object.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var buttons = {};
    $(".item").each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("image")) {
            buttons.image = 1;
        };
        if ($(this).hasClass("video")) {
            buttons.video = 1;
        };
    });
    // write buttons
    for (var type in buttons) {
      $('<button/>', {
        text: type,
        id: 'btn_'+ type,
        click: function () { alert('hi'); }
      }).appendTo('body');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**JSFIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/rWrCA/

You can easily use an array for the types and another array for whether or not those exist. That looks something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // a list of all types and a list of types that were found
    var allTypes = ["image", "video", "gallery"];
    var typesFound = [];

    // loop over all items and add types to the list of found types
    $(".item").each(function () {
        for (var idx = 0; idx < allTypes.length; idx++) {
          if ($(this).hasClass(allTypes[idx])) {
            if (typesFound.indexOf(allTypes[idx]) < 0) {
              typesFound.push(allTypes[idx]);
            }
          }
        }
    });

    // as in the original code - prove this worked by displaying alerts!
    for (var idx = 0; idx < typesFound.length; idx++) {
      alert(typesFound[idx] + ' found');
    }
});
```

I think that should do it!